# Batch get all but last two letters of user input

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I have the following code,

```
@echo off
cls
set /p word=
set string=%word%
set temp_str=%string%
set str_len=0
:lengthloop
if defined temp_str (
set temp_str=%temp_str:~1%
set /A str_len += 1
goto lengthloop )
echo %str_len%
set str_len=num
SET var2=%string:~0,-%num%
echo %var2%
SET var3=%string:~-2%
echo %var3%
pause
```

How can I get all but the last two letters of a users input, using the following doesn't work

```
SET var2=%string:~0,-%num%
```

Comment: I recommend switching to PowerShell rather than trying to do this in batch. (It's possible in batch, just painful.)

Comment: You never assign anything to the variable `num`.  You try to make the variable `str_len` the same as `num` but that just assigns the string num to `str_len`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /p word=
set string=%word%
set "num=2"
SET "var2=!string:~0,-%num%!"
echo %var2%
pause
```

or this, if you're already inside an expanded block:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /p word=
set string=%word%
set "num=2"
FOR /L %%G IN (%num%,1,%num%) DO SET "var2=!string:~0,-%%G!"
echo %var2%
pause
```

Comment: Dennis its not working for me and just in case I was misunderstood I want to get everything but the last two letters.

Comment: @jonathanx fixed, minor spelling mistake in my code

Comment: @jonathanx If my answer solved your problem, you should consider clicking the check to the left of it so people searching on google for the same problem can find it. See [this](//stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for why this is important.

Answer (score 0):

```
set "var2=%stringL~0,-2%"
```

should work to get the value of `string` except for the last 2 characters into `var2`.

(see

```
set /?
```

from the prompt for documentation - in fact getting all but the last 2 characters is shown as an example)

Comment: I think (although the question indicates otherwise) that the problem is with the line in which a variable is used instead of a hardcoded 2

Comment: @DennisvanGils: No doubt we'll find out in time. He repeats teh requirement from the title into the question body, and as Squishy says (but I've not verified) `num` is not assigned....